# MarkerClusters in OpenLayer 6.3.1 with WMS as source

Tags: javascript, markerclusterer, wms, openlayers-6

I am using OpenLayer version 6.3.1 and would like to know how to do a MarkerClusters using WMS data source.

My problem is that I don't know how to link the Cluster with WMS. the WMS source is a point.shp (geometrically)

I tried to replace the cluster sources by the WMS one, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code

```js
var ImageWMS = new ImageWMS({  
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ACCESSOINSMADA/wms',  
     params: {'LAYERS': 'ACCESSOINSMADA:csb2-pub', 'TILED': true},
     serverType: 'geoserver',
     transition: 0,
   
});
var ImageLayers = new ImageLayer({
    source: ImageWMS,
})

var distance = document.getElementById('distance');

var count = 20000;
var features = new Array(count);
var e = 3500000;
for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
  var coordinates = [2 * e * Math.random() - e, 2 * e * Math.random() - e];
  features[i] = new Feature(new Point(coordinates));
}

var source = new VectorSource({
  features: features,
});

var clusterSource = new Cluster({
  distance: parseInt(distance.value, 10),
  source: source,
});

var styleCache = {};
var clusters = new VectorLayer({
  source: clusterSource,
  style: function (feature) {
    var size = feature.get('features').length;
    var style = styleCache[size];
    if (!style) {
      style = new Style({
        image: new CircleStyle({
          radius: 10,
          stroke: new Stroke({
            color: '#fff',
          }),
          fill: new Fill({
            color: '#3399CC',
          }),
        }),
        text: new Text({
          text: size.toString(),
          fill: new Fill({
            color: '#fff',
          }),
        }),
      });
      styleCache[size] = style;
    }
    return style;
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A WMS output is (generally) an image, so you won't be able to change the data and cluster it in a client such as OpenLayers; to do that you'll need to fetch the data through say a WFS.

As an alternative to clustering points in a client, you can configure the WMS to serve out clustered points.

For an example see:

[WMS providing clustered points, shown in OpenLayers](http://ogc2.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/UGA_ARGI/ows?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&width=700&height=450&styles=&layers=ARTISANC&format=application/openlayers&crs=EPSG:4326&bbox=-2.000000,29.000000,4.500000,37.000000)